# Attaching jQuery library to the Ember jQuery

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I am integration an 'ember-cli' app into my 'main app'.

[image]

**main app**

- mylibs.js

  - jquery.js
  - my_validator_jquery.js

**ember cli app**

- vendor.js (ember generated)
- mylibs.js (from main app)
- app.js (ember generated)

**Ember cli app** is integrated into the main app by injecting **vendor.js** and **app.js**.

My issue is within my ember component when I call `this.$()`, well the `this.$()` is referring to the `Ember jQuery` and not the global `jQuery` from the **mylibs**.

This is a problem because the library (my_validator_jquery) gets attached to the global jQuery and not the ember jQuery.

My quick hack was to do the following

`$(this.$()).my_validator_jquery()` is this ok to do?

Or is there a cleaner way `to select the component view using the global jquery selector`?

Answer (score 2):

I your `brocfile.js` have the Ember-CLI not compile jQuery into the vendor file because you are loading jQuery already.

Which means that the version of jQuery that the Ember-CLI is loading is override any additions you have made to version of jQuery you loaded earlier. Also you don't want to load jQuery twice.

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  vendorFiles: {
    'jquery.js': false,
  }
});
```

Then you should be able to call your method like this.

```
this.$().my_validator_jquery()
```

I hope this helps
Cheers